# Trying to clone a list of GitLab Repo's with subprocess module

Tags: python, git, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to clone a big list of GitLab repositories from my GitLab Server. However, I'm having trouble getting the subprocess module to work. I've tried the answer to this question but it won't work for me. [Open Git Bash shell using a python script and then run a shell script in git bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114292/open-git-bash-shell-using-a-python-script-and-then-run-a-shell-script-in-git-bas)

Here is my code:

```
repo_list = [list_with_all_repository_names]

    for repo_name in repo_list:
        repo_url = f'https://url_to_my_gitlab_server/{repo_name}.git'
        p = subprocess.run(["C:/Users/my_user_name/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/git-bash.exe",
                            "C:/Users/my_user_name/Documents/Gitlab Repos/git-clone-shell.sh",
                            f"git clone {repo_name}"],
                         bufsize=-1,
                         executable=None,
                         stdin=None,
                         stdout=None,
                         stderr=None,
                         preexec_fn=None,
                         close_fds=False,
                         shell=False,
                         cwd="C:/Users/my_user_name/Documents/Gitlab Repos")
        time.sleep(20)
```

My shell script is simply a placeholder for the `f"git clone {repo_name}"` argument in the `subprocess.run` call, and therefore it's contents are no more than `$1`

Git bash opens but immediatly crashes and I don't know why. I've also tried to run the command directly in bash without a shell script, but this simply opens git bash and does nothing:

```
p = subprocess.run(
    [f'git clone {repo_url}'],
    bufsize=-1,
    executable='C:/Users/my_user_name/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/git-bash.exe',
    capture_output=True,
    cwd="C:/Users/my_user_name/Documents/Gitlab Repos"
)
```

I have the feeling that I'm close to a solution but I don't understand where it's going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "immediately crashes"? Note that git-bash (which is just bash, really, ported to Windows; it has nothing to do with Git), run with arguments, like this, will try to execute the given script, with `$1` set to the literal string `"git clone <name>"` complete with spaces. So it should run the commands *in* the script, and it's what's in the script that matters next (and you haven't shown that to us). But there are potential bad interactions between msys programs and non-msys programs on Windows, so perhaps that's what's biting you here.

Comment: What I mean by immediately crashes: I see git-bash open but it immediately closes after. I understand that like this the script will simply execute with argument set to literal string. This is why my shell script is nothing more than a placeholder ($1 and no more) for the 'git clone name' which is what I want to achieve. What did I not show to you? and what is an Msys program? Do you have any suggestions for improvement of the question? I still believe my code is faulty rather than a potential bad interaction

Comment: I don't use Windows, but I do read stuff on mailing lists. :-) An "msys program" is one that uses a particular library to fake a POSIX style environment on Windows. This gives people the ability to do a lot more Unix-like things. Some Git distributions use msys2, and bash uses msys2, and when running one msys2 program from another msys2 program there's some special magic to make them coordinate better. Whether your Python uses msys2, I have no idea. The thing we are missing is what's in the shell script (though now you've told us it's one line, or two lines, or something).

Comment: Edited question so that contents of my shell script are also explained

Comment: OK: I (on a Unix-like system) created a `foo.py` with `import subprocess; v = subprocess.run(["/usr/local/bin/bash", "bar.bash", "echo testing"], bufsize=-1, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False); print(v)`. Creating `./bar.bash` as executable with `$1` as its only line gives me `testing` on stdout, so this all works fine on the Unix-like system... (after `testing` I also get a `CompletedProcess(...)` from python3).

Comment: So, this really does look like it *should* all work. You could probably simplify it a lot though: there's no need to get bash itself involved here, if you just want to run `git clone`. Your Python code should be able to `subprocess.run(["git", "clone", f"..."], ...)`. Whether that would sidestep whatever mysterious thing is going wrong, well, we're back in "this is why I don't do Windows" territory...

Comment: I see. I'm bound to windows because this is my company laptop. Remembered I have a WSL installation - problem was solved in a jiffy =). Thanks for the help - appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by running the script in a WSL-environment, with the following subprocess setting:

```
for repo_name in repo_list:
    repo_url = f'url_to_gitlab_server/{repo_name}.git'
    p = subprocess.run(["git", "clone", f"{repo_url}"],
                     bufsize=-1,
                     stdin=None,
                     stdout=None,
                     stderr=None,
                     shell=False)
    print(p)
```